# can't reset the fill color of the svg path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I'm using svg in my application and i need to use class in my svg paths. Classes are working fine but i can't change the `fill` color of the svg path dynamically using `setAttribute`.

**CODE**

```
$('#path1')[0].setAttributeNS(null, "fill", 'blue');
```

**DEMO:** Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nX7g/) demo

How can  i change the fill color of the svg path dynamically if the path with class.
Any suggestions should be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `fill` CSS property:

```
$('#changeFill').click(function(){
    $('#path1').css('fill', 'blue');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/FD79p/)

Or if you want to keep the property setting in native JS (which would be odd as you're using jQuery to attach the event, but I'm not here to judge):

```
$('#path1')[0].style.fill = 'blue';
```